# How to bind select dropdownlist by selected value and other values from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project in php. When I bind select dropdown list with selected value as well as all others values inside the database the one value which is as selected will bind two times, one as first selected value and other as list values.
Below is my code.

```
$query1 = mysql_query("select * from pincode_master where pcode_id='1'");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) 
{
    $city_id = $row1['city_id'];
    $sql1="SELECT city_name from city_master where  city_id='$city_id'";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result1);
    @$city_name = $row[0];
        $query11 = "select * from city_master";
        $result11 = mysql_query($query11);
        echo "<select name = 'cityname'>";
            while (($row11 = mysql_fetch_row($result11)) != null)
            {
                echo "<option value = '{$row11['city_name']}'";
                if ($city_name == $city_name)
                    echo "selected = 'selected'";
                echo ">{$row11['city_name']}</option>";
            }
        echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: `if ($city_name == $city_name)` ? Huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your query outside loop.

Write your code as below:-

```
// Check query error 
$query1 = mysql_query( "select * from pincode_master where pcode_id='1'" ) or die( mysql_error());
// Check query error
$result11 = mysql_query( "select * from city_master" ) or die( mysql_error());
while ( $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query1 ) ) {
    $city_id = $row1['city_id'];
    echo "<select name = 'cityname'>";
    while ($row11 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result11 )) {
      $selected = $row11['city_id'] == $city_id ? "selected = 'selected'" : '';           
      echo "<option value = '{$row11['city_name']}' $selected >". $row11['city_name'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
 }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this -

is that what you want ?

```
<select name="yourselection">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <?php
 $msql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
 while($m_row = mysql_fetch_array($msql))        
        echo("<option value = '" . $m_row['table_column1'] . "'>" . $m_row['table_column2'] . "</option>");
    ?>
</select>
```

you will get more info [here](http://freefeast.info/tutorials-for-beginners/php-tutorials/dropdown-list-in-php-binding-dropdown-list-with-mysql-in-php/)